# Rails 4 and Jammit routing issue - should not use match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.1, jammit

I've upgraded to Rails 4.0.5 and i'm using Jammit 0.6.6.
When starting the server i get an error :

```
/home/haimh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.5/lib/action dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:191:in normalize_condition!:You should not use the match method in your router without specifying an HTTP method.
```

Looking at the stack trace i see that Jammit's routes.rb file is using the old routing API.

Is there any way of resolving this issue, beside updating the code manually in Jammit's routes.rb file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the `via`

like this:

adding `, via => [:get, :post]` to the end

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))' , :controller=> /admin\/[^\/]+/, :via => [:get,:post]
```

if you dont want to use match , you will have to have your routes inside the

```
resources :controller do
 get :action, :on => :collection
end
```

Comment: it did that as a work around, that why i asked if there is anyway avoiding updating Jammit's files